# Outlook Addin to Send updates to all attendees

Tags: outlook, vsto

I have created a simple addin; that adds some text to the meeting body. Now what i want to achieve is that when the organizer updates the meeting, the addin should send the update to all attendees; irrespective of the the selection made by the organizer.

Is there a way to do this in VSTO C# addins. In EWS you can achieve this by using

```
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AppointmentItem.ForceUpdateToAllAttendees` property.

Comment: What is your code that sets that property and sends the appointment?